# Chained rxjs Observable operators

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactivex

I'm relatively new to the ReactiveX principles, but I'm a big fan so far of what I've learned.  I have a challenge that I've put a little thought into, but I'd like to get a more experienced opinion on:

I have a few methods which return an Observable.  Each one creates an Observable in a similar manor and then chains the same exact operators.  Is there any way of abstracting those operators away such that I don't have to repeat this code each method.

For example, this is what I have right now:

```
    public get(endpoint: string, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(endpoint, requestOptions)
        .map((response: Response) => {
          let responseBody = response.json();
          return responseBody;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            let responseError = new ErrorResponse(error.status.toString(), error.json());
            return Observable.throw(responseError);
        })
        .publishReplay()
        .refCount()
        .share();
    }

    public put(endpoint: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.put(endpoint, body, requestOptions)
        .map((response: Response) => {
          let responseBody = response.json();
          return responseBody;
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          this.logger.logRequestError('PUT', endpoint, error);
          return Observable.throw(error);
        })
        .publishReplay()
        .refCount()
        .share();
    }
```

I'd like to take the map, catch, publishReplay, refCount, share operators and put them in their own operator, such that I can do something like this:

```
    public get(endpoint: string, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(endpoint, requestOptions).myOperator();
    }

    public put(endpoint: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.put(endpoint, body, requestOptions).myOperator();
    }

    // define myOperator as something like:

        .map((response: Response) => {
          let responseBody = response.json();
          return responseBody;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            let responseError = new ErrorResponse(error.status.toString(), error.json());
            return Observable.throw(responseError);
        })
        .publishReplay()
        .refCount()
        .share();

    // end definition
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? Using `bind()` you can defer the execution of your http call. I don't know which library you are using, if `http.get()` returns an Observable then you can just call it and pass the returned observable to `handleHttpCall` because Observables are (almost always) lazy and will not run code until subscribed upon.

```
public get(endpoint:string, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<any> {
  return handleHttpCall(this.http.get.bind(endpoint, requestOptions));
}

private handleHttpCall(httpAction) {
  return httpAction()
       .map((response: Response) => {
          let responseBody = response.json();
          return responseBody;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            let responseError = new ErrorResponse(error.status.toString(), error.json());
            return Observable.throw(responseError);
        })
        .publishReplay()
        .refCount()
        .share();
}
```

Comment: Mark, thank you.  This is actually exactly what I'm doing now.  I didn't know if there was more a "reactive" way of dealing with it, where I could simply add an operator on the end of the http.get() call. (Which yes, my http.get() does return an observable.)

Comment: since your http.get() returns an observable you can skip the bind() piece. A more reactive way to convert a promise to an observable would be to use `Rx.Observable.defer(() => this.http.get(endpoint, requestOptions))`